# Yii2 ~ SQL JOIN 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm pretty new to YII2 so I don't really know how this works but I want to join tables on factuur_id so I can display the products in my invoice (factuur)

normally you would do something like this:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
                die("Database Connection Failed: " . mysqli_error() . "(". mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
               );
            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM facturen JOIN producten ON facturen.factuur_id = producten.factuur_id WHERE facturen.factuur_id = 13";

            if ($result =  mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
                    echo $result;
```

but in yii2 you have something like a query builder (?)
so how does that work?

I want to display the products (producten) by the right invoice via ID

[image: my relations]

Comment: if you  have relation between document  you could use  the relation between models adding  in the model the relation you need  and the using getter you can retrive the related  view you need  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data

Comment: Documentation is pretty good, so just read something from Scais link and you should understand everything.

Answer (score 0):

Working with database is not a feature easy to explain in just a few words. I suggest you to read the guide about it : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-README.html#working-with-databases . But here are some quick information.

In a nutshell, you should try to create ActiveRecord objects. This can be done easily by enabling the "gii" module in your config and going to `http://[your_host]/gii/model` to generate the active record class for your tables.

Then you can do something like this for your requests.

```
class Companies extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {} // auto-generated
class Facturen extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {} // auto-generated

function tryJoin()
{
    $cTableName = Companies::tableName();
    $fTableName = Facturen::tableName();

    $query = Companies->find();
    $query->leftJoin($fTableName, "{$cTableName}.company_id = {$fTableName}.company_id");
    $query->where([{$fTableName}.person_id => 123456]);
    $companyList = $query->all();
    // the result is a list of Company objects
}
```

Or if you don't want to create ActiveRecord entities, there is the quick way with a DB command.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM companies
        LEFT JOIN facturen ON companies.company_id = facturen.company_id
        WHERE facturen.person_id = 123456;";
$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql, $params);
$arrayList = $command->queryAll();
// The result is a list of array mapping company table column names.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have generated models with db relations, then you can do something like this: 
*[assuming you have a relation named `producten` in your model Facturen.php]*

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getProducten()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Producten::className(), ['factuur_id' => 'factuur_id']);
}
```

**In your Controller**

```
$data = Facturen::find()
        ->joinWith('producten')
        ->where([Facturen::tableName().'.factuur_id' => '13'])
        ->one();
```

**Then you can access the objects as:**

```
$data->company_id; // from table facturen

$data->producten['product_name'];
// from table producten because related tables are returned as arrays
```